# Facing problem at updating shopping cart in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, shopping-cart

I am developing a shopping cart for an online bookstore. I can update the cart easily without put any condition.

Whenever the user updates the quantity, I want that, this quantity should be equal or less than the quantity which I have in my database.  So I put a condition here.

**This is my update cart function in the controller:**

```
public function update_cart()
{
    $contents = $this->input->post();

    foreach ($contents as $content) 
    {
        $info = array(

        'rowid'=> $content['rowid'],
        'qty' => $content['qty']

        );
        if($content['qty'] < '0')
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', '*Quantity can not be less than 0 or negative value.');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->cart->update($info);
        }

    }
        redirect('cart');
}
```

This condition is okay.

But the problem occurred whenever I put the else if() {} condition, to check the quantity given by the user is less or equal to my quantity in the database. Then this does not work or take the update.

**This is my code with else if condition:**

```
public function update_cart()
{

    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $books = $this->admin_model->get_book_detail($id);         

    $contents = $this->input->post();

    foreach ($contents as $content) 
    {
        $info = array(

        'rowid'=> $content['rowid'],
        'qty' => $content['qty']

        );
        if($content['qty'] < '0')
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', '*Quantity can not be less than 0 or negative value.');
        }
       else if($content['qty'] > $books->quantity)
       {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', '*This much quantity is not in stock.');
       }

        else
        {
            $this->cart->update($info);
        }

    }
        redirect('cart');
}
```

what is the problem in my conditions? Especially in else if() condition!

Comment: Variable `$books` - __where__ it is defined?

Comment: @u_mulder this variable defined at the controller like [$this->load->model('admin_model');
  $books = $this->admin_model->get_book_detail($id);]

Comment: I __do not__ see it defined in `update_cart` method. Do you see?

Comment: @u_mulder see the edited one. But this is also not working!

Comment: Now - what is `$id`?

Comment: $id is from books table at the database. But why my first code is running fine?

Comment: Do you understand your code? `$id` __is not defined anywhere__. Your previous code works because it does not use any `$books` or `$id` variable.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I am a beginner at CodeIgniter so that I am facing the problem. I define the $id at update_cart($id) but this also not working. **Where should I define the $id?**

Comment: Don't you think that `$content['rowid']` is id of the book?

Comment: sorry I can't use that properly. Can please give me the explanation at the answer. **How I can do this?**